# Creating a script or find an add on for google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I am new to coding, google scripts and add ons.  I want to create or find a script that will lock my google sheets on a specific day each week (or specific date).  I have a very basic understanding of writing code in java- just enough to know that I don't know what I need to accomplish this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask].

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a script as an answer, you could setup a [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) to fire on those days (Look for time-driven triggers). Then, write a function that is based off of the [protect()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#protect) class. There you can choose the permissions of who can edit the file among other things, effectively locking your sheet.